# Looking for a function with two-humps.

Tags: functions

New here and this might be a foolish question... I'm looking for a mathematical function that has two 'humps' and is somewhat efficient to compute. I'm looking for something like this: min(abs(x), a) where a is positive,  but with the ends of the 'valley' going downwards in the y-direction exponentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if we want a function $f(x)$ that decays exponentially in both directions, we want $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x)$ goes to $-\infty$ in both directions. We still want $g$ to have two humps (local maxima). Between them, it should have a local minimum. So if $g$ is a polynomial, we want it to be quartic.

One option is $g(x) = x^2(1-x^2)$, which has a double root at $0$ and two more roots at $\pm1$, so it will have two local maxima in between those. This gives us $f(x) = e^{x^2(1-x^2)}$.

[image]

If we don't care about $g(x)$ being a polynomial, then we can get the same shape for $g(x)$ with $g(x) = -||x|-1|$ and $f(x) = e^{-||x|-1|}$.

[image]

If you only figuratively asked for the tails to be exponential, there's also $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^4+1}$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about $x^2\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}$, which has the nice property you can reuse the evaluation of $x^2$.  The variant $x^2 \mathrm{e}^{1-x^2}$ has the property that it also passes through the points $(\pm 1, 1)$ (as does your example when $a = 1$).

[image: Plot of the variant]

Comment: This is super random but this is exactly what i needed, thanks !